# Custom link in order grid not able to access custom controller but forward to order details page

Tags: magento2, order-grid, admin-controller

I've successfully create a column in order grid page. The

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="is_erp_synced" class="Test\OrderIntegration\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Erp">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Erp</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Erp.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\OrderIntegration\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Erp extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $order_id = $order->getId();
                $order_status = $order->getStatus();
                $sync_status = $order->getData("is_erp_synced");
                $html_header = "<a href='".$this->context->getUrl('test/integration/index/', ['id' => $order_id]).">";
                $html_end = "</a>";

                /*$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/erplog.log');
                $logger = new \Zend_Log();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info($order->getStatus());*/




                switch ($order_status) {
                    case "pending":
                        //pending order
                        $erp_status = "Not yet";
                        break;
                    case "processing":
                        //processing order
                        if ($sync_status == 0) {
                            $erp_status =  html_entity_decode($html_header."re-sync".$html_end);
                        } else {
                            $erp_status = "Uploaded";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Complete":
                        //canceled order
                        if ($sync_status == 0) {
                            $erp_status =  html_entity_decode($html_header."<button>re-sync</button></a>".$html_end);
                        } else {
                            $erp_status = "Uploaded";
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        $erp_status = "No need";
                        break;

                }

                // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return erp_status
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $erp_status;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

When i onhover the link of the href, it shows the correct controller path e.g . http://www.example.com/admin/test/integration/index/id/13/key/s2dfjksdfj123122d0dnkljdldf, but when i click it, finally it will redirect to sales order view page. http://www.example.com/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/13/

Even i change the link to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it stills redirect me to  sales order view page, anyone know what is the problem?

remarks:

Seems like the problem is even I removed the hyper link, and then click the order row (it show cursor when onhover), it will also go to order view page. How to disable disable onhover click to order view page when onhover custom column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution is, you have to disable the default action on grid row

For this, try to add this line in your ***sales_order_grid.xml*** under config item section

```
<item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="is_erp_synced" class="Test\OrderIntegration\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Erp">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Erp</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Just tried, it works, thanks

Comment: Glad, it worked for you :)